# EMR bootstrap action run as root best practices

Tags: bash, root, amazon-emr

I need to run an EMR bootstrap action script entirely as root (the script is not short and contains many conditions so i don't think i can just go ahead and run sudo before every line)
the only idea i had is write the script into a file (inside the bootstrap script or in s3 and download it) and run `sudo <filepath>` to do it but it seems like a bad solution, anyone has any best practices for it?

Comment: why do u think its bad?

Comment: well first of all sudo is not a complete replacement to running with root, i ended up doing this anyway so it doesn't really matter anymore. i don't think there's a better solution